# how to fetch user experience from linkedin using restapi

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I'm building a website using the PHP, and I'm now building integration with LinkedIn. I am using an rest api. I have already get profile image, name,education and skill, but i am unable to found work history i.e experience of user. 
Does anybody know how I can actually get the **"experience of user"**

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for just  [that](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/positions)

Answer (score 1):

Note that LinkedIn changed their API policy and **you will no longer be able to pull many of the fields you are looking for come May 12, 2015**. See more: https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition